# How to deny access of a user group on particular views of a joomla component in admin panel. Not for whole component

Tags: joomla, acl, joomla3.0, user-permissions, usergroups

I'm working with joomla 3.

Consider a joomla **component with 6 views**.

And two user groups named **user-group1, user-group2**.

My requirement is like this:

**user-group1** should be able to **access the first three views** of the component.( access on last three views should be denied for user-group1).

**user-group2** should be able to **access the last three views** of the component.( access on first three views should be denied for user-group2).

Comment: You can use dot separated names in the access.xml.

Comment: front end, or back end access?

Comment: Can U plz explain it little brief? @elin

Comment: Have you made access.xml? Do you know what it looks like in the normal case?

Comment: yes i have used. do i need to make changes here `<action name="core.create" `